# Location Monitoring when app is closed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, location

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Alternative to startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881975/alternative-to-startmonitoringsignificantlocationchanges)

I'm developing an app where I need to call a web service whenever the user's location has changed by 3 kilometers. It needs to work when the app is closed (not in the background, but closed).

I've tried the `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` method but it's too inaccurate, as it triggers when the user has moved from one network cell to another (as I understood when i was searching).

And as far as I know, only the `startMonitoringForRegion` and the `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` methods will relaunch the application to the background to perform some code when the location has changed (or entered/exited a region).

Any solution on how to overcome this issue?

Comment: That's true, but it's also inaccurate, it triggers at least every 6 km when i tested it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK,
I've solved this problem by doing the following.

- When the app launches for the first time, create a new region with the desired diameter( which is 3 KM in my case).
- When the user exits the region, create another region with a center point of it's current location and a diameter of 3 KM (again, which is in my case).

and so on...

there might be some overlaps in the regions but it will still do the work.

if anyone has a better solution please share it. :)